# Why does "acall" instruction does not work in Atmel 89C2051 microcontroller?

Tags: assembly, embedded, microcontroller, firmware, 8051

I tried it with Keil-µVision and Asem-51 but they still plugging that it is an syntax error. Here is my code:

```
acall subroutine1
.
.
.

subroutine1:
.
.
.
ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AT89C2051 part definitely supports the ACALL instruction (so claims the [data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0368.pdf) and I've successfully used it myself).

What is the *exact* error that you are seeing in each assembler? Does the rest of your source compile OK?

Can you post the exact source that is giving an error (or make a small example that demonstrates the issue if the code itself is confidential)?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The subroutine definition must go first before calling it:

```
   org 0
   sjmp start

subroutine1:
   .
   .
   .
   ret

start:
  .
  .
  .
  acall subroutine1
```

Thanks psmears for confirming that "acall" instruction really works for AT89C2051.

Comment: You should be able to call subroutines later in your source file. How to do this will depend on your assembler (Keil / Assem-51 / etc), but if there's an option for "two pass" assembly that should do the trick...